# How to rebuild system reserved partition for uefi

Tags: boot, uefi

I had windows 10 and I wanted to run dual boot with lubuntu. I had to delete system reserved partition and use it for `/boot/efi` because for some reason it showed that I can't create more than 4 primary partitions. but in the end that didn't workout and showed `An operating system wasn't found` on booting. I don't understand about boot loaders and what was the problem so I enable UEFI and added `EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi`. everything works normally and I didn't had any trouble with that, but now I need to dual boot with windows because I have few programs that don't run on linux.

how can I rebuild system reserved partition and add it to UEFI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure out what are my problems. I installed windows 10 in legacy mood and my disk has MBR partition table.
First mistake was, I installed lubuntu in UEFI mode and tried to run it on legacy mood, so it didn't work.
Second mistake was, trying to fix and build windows 10 to run on UEFI mode. windows only run EFI on GPT disks but mine is MBR.

The best thing to do is reinstall windows 10 in legacy mood without creating system reserved partition because MBR is limited to 4 primary partition.

I boot lubuntu in UEFI mode. When I need to run windows 10, I select boot from hard drive.

[image: screenshot of boot menu]

(This is the only way I found to solve my problem without losing all my data. I thought it would helpful somehow, so I leave it here instead of deleting this stupid question.)

Answer (score 1):

As per this [link](https://www.datanumen.com/blogs/4-solutions-system-reserved-partition-deleted-mistake/) you can rebuild the system Partition:

- Firstly, boot the Windows-based computer via Windows installation media.
- Then in the first installation screen, press “Shift + F10” keys, which will bring out the Command Prompt.
- Next input “bootrec /fixmbr” and hit “Enter” key.
- Later enter “diskpart” and press “Enter”.
- Then type “select disk 0” and hit “Enter”.
- Later input “list partition” and tap on “Enter”.
- Type “select partition n (n is the Windows OS partition)” and press “Enter”.
- Input “active” and hit “Enter”.
- Subsequently, input “Exit” and hit “Enter”.
- After that, type “bootrec /fixboot” and tap on “Enter”.
- Next input “bootrec /rebuildbcd” and click “Enter”.
- Ultimately, you can close the Command Prompt and shut down your PC. Then try to boot from the drive that has been repaired just now.

There are other references too [link2](https://www.prime-expert.com/articles/a16/rebuild-system-reserved-partition-from-scratch/) might be helpful

Comment: I done this but nothing good happened. files in USB drive are overridden and damaged can't boot again. There are new folder crated as `EFI/Microsoft`. I set UEFI to `EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi` but nothing happens.